# Mysql Group table values and display their total

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a table which stores inventory of a kitchen. :

Structure of the table :  `tbl_inv`

```
╔══════════════╦══════════╦══════╗
║ MATERIALNAME ║ QUANTITY ║ UNIT ║
╠══════════════╬══════════╬══════╣
║ chicken      ║        5 ║ kgs  ║
║ cheese       ║       10 ║ kgs  ║
║ chicken      ║       10 ║ pcs  ║
║ cheese       ║       10 ║ kgs  ║
║ chicken      ║       10 ║ kgs  ║
╚══════════════╩══════════╩══════╝
```

I want this output on my html page -

```
╔═════════════╦══════════╦══════╗
║MATERIALNAME ║ TOTALSUM ║ UNIT ║
╠═════════════╬══════════╬══════╣
║ cheese      ║       20 ║ kgs  ║
║ chicken     ║       15 ║ kgs  ║
║ chicken     ║       10 ║ pcs  ║
╚═════════════╩══════════╩══════╝
```

I have tried following SQL,

```
SELECT materialname, SUM(quantity) totalValue FROM tbl_inv GROUP BY materialname";
```

I dont know what should I have to use in mysql command to get this output.

Comment: SELECT `materialname`, SUM(quantity) totalValue FROM `tbl_inv` GROUP BY `materialname`";

Comment: Usually it is best to add what you have tried, *why that didn't work*, and *what exactly you are having trouble with* to your question when you ask it. For example in this question you could have stated your query above, and said "I don't know how to group by two columns in one query". Otherwise we can misread your question that you don't know `GROUP BY` at all and start to wonder if Google is down for you.

Comment: ya my bad i didn't mentioned that. I got it working with the answer below just wondering how to store those values in php variables and display on the page.

Comment: Like I said below, ask a new question. But do some research first and when you *do* ask, put what you have tried and what, specifically, you need help with.

Comment: @SagarGajara : Look at my answer with Sorting option...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically grouped them by `materialName` and `unit`

```
SELECT  materialName, SUM(quantity) totalSum, unit
FROM    tableName
GROUP   BY materialName, unit
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eff51/1)

OTHER(s)

- [GROUP BY and other *AGGREGATE* Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)

Comment: perfect but i am unable to understand how to put those values in php variables and then display on the html page ?

Comment: @SagarGajara And that would be a new question. (Which is most likely a duplicate of either the PHP manual or (a) question(s) here.)

Comment: @JW. : having just one issue man, material name and unit are displayed properly but quantity doesn't show up....please help in this then m done .

Comment: what do you mean by *Quantity doesn't show up*? The demo display the column.

Comment: @JW. : $show_dis="SELECT `material_name`, SUM(`quantity`) totalsum, unit FROM `tbl_inv` GROUP BY `material_name`,`unit`";
$ary_qury_ass= mysql_query($show_dis);
$mat_nm  = $rs_arr_select['material_name'];
$qty_mat  = $rs_arr_select['qunaity'];
$unit  = $rs_arr_select['unit'];

..When i echo those variables quantity shows blank value

Comment: you are selecting *inexistent* column, try this instead `$rs_arr_select['totalsum'];`

Comment: @JW. : yup Worked !! ...Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this Group by with Sorting Query...

```
SELECT  materialName MATERIALNAME, SUM(quantity) TOTALSUM, unit UNIT
FROM    tableName
GROUP   BY MATERIALNAME, UNIT
ORDER   BY MATERIALNAME
```